# How to handle unit conversions while interacting with FMUs?

Tags: python, modelica, fmi, unit-conversion, pyfmi

I have a python script that filters and lists the parameters, their units and default values from a fmu using the `read_model_description` function from FMPy library and writes in an excel sheet ([related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492290/is-there-a-way-to-list-of-parameters-of-fmu-or-of-submodel-in-fmu-using-the-py)). Then using the `simulate_fmu` function the script simulates the fmu and writes the results with units back in the excel sheet.

In filtering the parameters and output variable, I use this line to get their units.
`unit = variable.declaredType.unit if hasattr(variable.declaredType,'unit') else '-'`

While interacting with the fmu, the parameter and variable values are in default SI units. I guess this is according to the FMI standard. However, in the `modelDescription.xml` under `<UnitDefinitions>` I see that there is information regarding the default SI unit to displayUnit conversion. For example:

```
<Unit
      name="Pa">
      <BaseUnit kg="1"
        m="-1"
        s="-2"/>
      <DisplayUnit
        name="bar"
        factor="1E-05"/>
      <DisplayUnit
        name="ftH2O"
        factor="0.0003345525633129686"/>
</Unit>
```

Is there a way to be able to get the parameter values and output variables in displayUnits if the conversion factors are already available in the modelDescription.xml?

Or is there a easier solution using python libraries like pint that can act as a wrapper around fmu to convert the units in desired unit system (i.e. SI to IP) while interacting with it?

Comment: Support for Units and Display Units has been added in [FMPy 0.2.24](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/releases/tag/v0.2.24). See [issue 177](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/issues/177) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [FMPy source](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) I did not find any place where unit conversion is implemented.

But all the relevant information is read in [model_description.py](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/fmpy/model_description.py).

The display unit information ends up in `modelDescription.unitDefinitions`. E.g. to convert a value `val = 1.013e5 # Pa` to all defined display units, the following might work:

```
for unit in modelDescription.unitDefinitions:
  if unit.name == "Pa":
    for display_unit in unit.displayUnits:
      print(display_unit.name)
      # not sure about the brackets here
      print( (val - display_unit.offset)/display_unit.factor ) 
    break
```

Take a look at the [FMI Specification 2.01](https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/releases/download/v2.0.1/FMI-Specification-2.0.1.pdf), chapter *2.2.2 Definition of Units (UnitDefinitions)* to get the full picture.